# Angular 2 components doesn't render correctly when used with router outlet

Tags: angular, angular-component-router, flickity

I'm developing a simple angular 2 website, using angular 2 lazy routing.
I use flickity slider to implement a slider in the home page,
the problem is :
when i declare the slider component in the app component (root compoenent)

**app.component**

```
<app-topnav></app-topnav>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<app-home-slider></app-home-slider>  <------- the slider component !
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<hr class="divider">
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

the slider renders without problem,
but when I declare the slider component in a home-page component who is called in router-outlet using the lazy loading, the pictures are there but the slider doesn't work,

**home-page.component**

```
<app-home-slider></app-home-slider>  <------- the slider component !
<app-plaques></app-plaques>
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Accueil-*', loadChildren: './Pages/home-page/home-page.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'A-propos-*', loadChildren: './Pages/about-page/about-page.module#AboutPageModule' },
  { path: 'Contact-*', loadChildren: './Pages/contact-page/contact-page.module#ContactPageModule' },
  { path: 'Maladies-*', loadChildren: './Pages/diseases-page/diseases-page.module#DiseasesPageModule' },
  { path: 'Pharmacie-*', loadChildren: './Pages/drugs-page/drugs-page.module#DrugsPageModule' },
  { path: 'Laboratoire-*', loadChildren: './Pages/laboratory-page/laboratory-page.module#LaboratoryPageModule' },
  { path: 'Paiements-assurances-*', loadChildren: './Pages/payments-page/payments-page.module#PaymentsPageModule' },
  { path: 'Formules-sante-*', loadChildren: './Pages/products-page/products-page.module#ProductsPageModule' },
  { path: 'Symptomes-signes-*', loadChildren: './Pages/symptomes-page/symptomes-page.module#SymptomesPageModule' },
  { path: 'Rendez-vous-*', loadChildren: './Pages/appointments-page/appointments-page.module#AppointmentsPageModule' },
  { path: 'Docteurs-*', loadChildren: './Pages/symptomes-page/symptomes-page.module#SymptomesPageModule' },
  { path: 'Blog-*', loadChildren: './Pages/blog-page/blog-page.module#BlogPageModule' },

];

export const AppRoutes = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Could you add your app.routing.ts or similar?

Comment: Ok ! just edited !

Answer (score 0):

after reading the flickity doc many times, i figured it out:
when using WebPack we must  add

```
var Flickity = require('flickity');
```

Comment: Where did you add that?

Answer (score 0):

in fact this not the actual answer, to resolve this issue, i just edited en encapsulation to none, you can do so in the Component like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-random',
  templateUrl: 'my-random.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None <---------- ADD THIS
})
```

you can read more about encapsulation in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation)